# Framing for a load-bearing wall pocket door install

Tags: framing, pocket-door

I live in the province of Ontario and am getting ready to frame for a pocket door in a load-bearing wall with a rough opening of 66.5 inches (1.68m). It's standard 2x4 framing and it's a bungalow so just supporting the ceiling and roof.

My question is what size header do I need to put in?

I tried looking at the OBC which was confusing but if I'm reading it right Table A-12 says I need a 3-ply 2x8 header. But that would sit proud of the rest of the 2x4 framing. Is there a way to use a more standard 2-ply header that I can make the same thickness as the rest of the framing or no? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The header has to distribute the load above it to the sides .. so if you want to go not as high you need something better able to take the load ... So stiffer timbers or perhaps steel / concrete lintels?  Really depends on what the code says &/or what an engineer will sign off on.

Comment: 3 ply 2x8 or 2 ply 2x 10 for under 6ft span are equivalent

Comment: Reviewing the OBC again I think I should actually be referencing Table A-13 which would allow 2-ply 2x10s. I don't know if anyone else has thoughts on this? Thanks.